sql query only inserting 5 rows
I have this table that I am creating with sql query
CREATE TABLE if not exists User (
    id bigint AUTO_INCREMENT,
    coins bigint not null,
    level bigint not null,
    country VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

I want to insert 3 million entries
with coins being a random number from 0-99999
level being a random number from 1-100
with country being a random country from the 5 countries in the list
INSERT INTO User (coins, level, country)
SELECT
    FLOOR(RAND() * 100000) AS coins,
    FLOOR(RAND() * 100 + 1) AS level,
    countries.country AS country
FROM
    (SELECT "SPAIN" AS country UNION SELECT "FRANCE" UNION SELECT "UK" UNION SELECT "USA" UNION SELECT "GERMANY") countries
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3000000;

Yet when I get this I only get 5 rows. Adding 1 from each country. How can I fix this ?

the (SELECT "SPAIN" AS country UNION SELECT "FRANCE" UNION SELECT "UK" UNION SELECT "USA" UNION SELECT "GERMANY") countries only return 5 rows. so the insert can also insert 5 rows

What is MySQL version?

8.0.28:oracle @Akina

Does that make difference for this ? @Akina

@umarkaa General hint: Use UNION ALL rather than UNION in case you are sure the results are all different. That's much faster.

INSERT INTO User (coins, level, country)
WITH RECURSIVE
  cte (id) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT id + 1 FROM cte LIMIT 3000000)
SELECT
    FLOOR(RAND() * 100000) AS coins,
    FLOOR(RAND() * 100 + 1) AS level,
    ELT(RAND() * 4 + 1, "SPAIN", "FRANCE", "UK", "USA", "GERMANY")
FROM cte;

fiddle

hi thank you for this! I ran into iteration limite problem and I tried this command, SET GLOBAL cte_max_recursion_depth=10000; which seemed to have no affect,

@umarkaa Do not set global setting (do this almost never), set session one.
